# How to determine the appropriate number of lags when using Newey-West (or HAC) standard errors

Tags: stata, panel-data, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, neweywest

I have an unbalanced panel dataset where both autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity are present. I have read, in the Stata manual, that the **newey** command (see Newey-West, 1987) is one way in which these two problems may be addressed simultaneously. However, my understanding is that I must stipulate a **lag(m)** option, where autocorrelation at lags greater than m can be ignored. My question is how to determine what 'm' should be? Is there some way to determine how many lags I should be using?

I have found some discussion online about a type of stationary test where I would calculate first differences, second differences, etc. and then run the test for autocorrelation. Once I reach "stationary", I should know how many lags to use. But, I can't find any information on what this test is or how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it is possible to choose the optimal lag length based on the AIC or BIC. Eviews has a built-in function to do this.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is going to expand on what @Achim mentioned as "the growth rate of this lag length parameter". Newey & West (1987, Econometrica, p. 705) show that their estimator for the covariance matrix is consistent if the lag length $m$ satisfies the following two conditions:

1. The lag length $m$ grows with the sample size $T$. Specifically,

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}m(T)=+\infty.$$

2. The lag length $m$ grows at a slower rate than $T^{1/4}$:

$$\lim_{T\to \infty}[m(T)/T^{1/4}]=0.$$

*(These are obviously not the only conditions for the consistency of the estimators, but the other conditions are not directly related to the lag length.)*

In light of the above, **many practitioners seem to simply set $m$ to the integer part of $T^{1/4}$**, see e.g. Greene (Econometric Analysis, 7th edition, section 20.5.2, p. 960).

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I do not know the details about the panel version of the Newey-West standard errors and their implementation in Stata. The references I give below are for time series data (without panels) but hopefully these take you a step further.

In the classic Newey & West (1987, *Econometrica*) paper, they only consider the growth rate of this lag length parameter. Some implementations do use lag selection heuristics based on this growth rate, though. A proper nonparametric lag selection procedure is introduced Newey & West (1994, *Review of Economic Studies*). Alternatively, there are parametric bandwidth selection procedures (based on AR(1) or ARMA(1,1) approximations) that can also be employed - suggested by Andrews (1991, *Econometrica*) and refined by Andrews & Monahan (1992, *Econometrica*).